# integral factors of an irrational number

Tags: arithmetic, irrational-numbers

If the radicand of a square root is a non-square (making the root an irrational), and if the non-square is either a prime number, or a composite number that does not have a square divisor (other than 1), does this mean that the square root is not divisible by an integral divisor (that it does not have an integral factor)?

For example, $\sqrt{200} = \sqrt{100\times2} = \sqrt{100}\times\sqrt{2}=10\sqrt{2}$, so $\sqrt{200}$ has an integral factor of 10 (is divisible by 10). However, $\sqrt{6} = \sqrt{3\times2} = \sqrt{3}\times\sqrt{2}$

I'm mainly wondering for the purpose of reducing fractions that contain radicals and integers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The phrase "does not have an integral factor" is a little imprecise, since anything has an integral factor: we have $x=17\left(\frac{x}{17}\right)$.

So we rephrase the question. Suppose that $n$ is a square-free integer. Do there exist integers $d$ and $k$, with $k\gt 1$, such that
$$\sqrt{n}=k\sqrt{d}?\tag{1}$$
Once we express the question like that, the answer is quick. Suppose to the contrary that there are integers $k,d$, with $k\gt 1$, such that (1) holds. Squaring both sides, we get $n=k^2d$, so $n$ is divisible by a square greater than $1$.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but I only follow you up until statement (1). You say that $n$ is divisible by a square, but I'm wondering if $\sqrt{n}$ is divisible by k. Could you please elaborate?

Comment: By $\sqrt{n}$ divisible by $k\gt 1$, I assume you mean that there is an **integer** $d$ such that $\sqrt{n}=k\sqrt{d}$. Then the solution above says this cannot happen if $n$ is square-free. If you allow things like $\sqrt{6}=2\sqrt{3/2}$, then $\sqrt{n}$ is always divisible by any positive integer $k$.

Comment: So you're saying that if $n$ is a square-free integer and $d$ is an integer, then integer $k$ does not exist?

Comment: There is then no integer $k\gt 1$ such that $\sqrt{n}=k\sqrt{d}$. Proof given in the post.

Comment: OK, you've definitely answered my question, but I'm not following the reasoning. Is this a proof by contradiction? You make the assumption that $n$ is a square-free integer, and that $k$ and $d$ are integers ($k>1$). How does the fact that $n$ is divisible by a square greater than 1 cause a contradiction? All we assumed was that $n$ is a square-free integer. But plenty of square free integers are divisible by perfect squares. I must be misinterpreting something...

Comment: Your question was about integers $n$ that are not divisible by any integer greater than $1$. These are usually called *square-free*. So we did operate by contradiction. We were given a square-free $n$. We supposed that there were integers  $k\gt 1$, $d$ such that $\sqrt{n}=k\sqrt{d}$. Squaring, we concluded that $k^2$ divides $n$. This contradicts the fact that $n$ is square-free.

Comment: Yes got it. Thanks!

Comment: You are welcome. It is a good thing to want clarity about the logic of an argument.

Comment: With your knowledge and attitude, you'd make a outstanding teacher (professionally that is) if you're not one already.