# Is a non-zero integral multiple of an irrational number guaranteed to be irrational?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, irrational-numbers

I got to wondering if a non-zero integral multiple of any irrational number is guaranteed to be irrational?   This seems intuitive but I can't prove it to myself.

There is an [answer on this site](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/497712/integral-factors-of-an-irrational-number) with regard to factors, but not multiples of irrationals.

If someone could sketch a quick proof, my day would be golden. Thanks!

Comment: Let $\alpha$ ba an irrational number, $m$ a nonzero integer.  Suppose for contradiction that $m \alpha$ were rational, Then we would have $$m \alpha = \frac{p}{q}$$ for some integers $p$ and $q \neq 0$, giving $$\alpha = \frac{p}{mq},$$ which contradicts the fact that $\alpha$ is irrational.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Yes, it is guaranteed. Suppose for the sake of contradiction that $\alpha$ is irrational, and that $n\alpha$ is rational for some non-zero integer $n$. In other words, suppose
$$n\alpha=\frac{a}{b}$$
for some non-zero integer $n$ and rational number $\frac{a}{b}$. Then this implies
$$\alpha=\frac{a}{bn}$$
contradicting the **definition** of $\alpha$ being irrational.

Comment: You would’t necessarily have an integer on the RHS of the first equation; you’d have to assume a quotient of integers.

Comment: Just misread the question, edited.

Comment: You never actually use the assumption that $\alpha$ is irrational, so you could just as well take it out..  Just assume $n\alpha$ is rational and show that $\alpha$ is rational; then you've proven the contrapositive.

Comment: Wow. easy when you say it ;^)    Thanks, Zev.  answer accepted.  (thanks to Jordan too).

Comment: @mathmandan: see https://gowers.wordpress.com/2010/03/28/when-is-proof-by-contradiction-necessary/ for some discussion, in particular which argues that any proof of irrationality must be by contradiction in *some* sense.

Comment: @BenMillwood, thanks, and I think my comment is pretty much in agreement with Gowers when he says "proof by contradiction is a very useful tool, but try not to use it unless you really need it." Anyway, all I was saying was: (1) when you can remove an assumption from an argument and leave the rest unchanged, you probably might as well do it, and (2) mathematicians can and do distinguish between contradiction and contraposition. But these things are better debated at http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/262828/proof-by-contradiction-vs-prove-the-contrapositive/705291#705291